# How do I create a variable in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

How do I create a variable in Visual Basic?

Comment: This should be covered by tutorials.

Comment: Absolutely no research effort

Answer (score 2):

- http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/vbscript_variables.asp

Answer (score 0):

The general syntax is:

```
Dim variableName As [DataType] [= *initialValue*]
```

For example:

```
Dim carSpeed As Double = 5.7
```

Answer (score 0):

Examples;

- Dim VariableName As Double
- Dim VariableName As Single